# ¿Cómo obtener el contenido de un SELECT(texto) con javascript o jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

QUIERO COMPARAR EL CONTENIDO DE UN select!!!!!  NO ESTOY COMPARANDO EL VALOR DEL select

tengo este codigo y quiero validar que `$(this).val() == linea` pero tengo que cambiar `$(this).val()` por `$(this).text()` para poder hacer la comparacion pero no me funciona me sale en blanco y con `val()` si me arroja el valor pero quiero comparar el contenido del campo en lugar del valor

```
        $("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
            console.log($(this).text());
            if($(this).val() == linea){
                repetido = 1;
            }
        });
```

// con este obtenego el valor

```
 $(this).val()
```

// con este deberia obtener el texto que esta en el input (pero no funciona)

```
$(this).text()
```

La solución puede ser en jquery o javascript no hay problema.

ya intente esto

```
        $("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
            console.log($('select[name="lineas"] option:selected').text());
            if($('select[name="lineas"] option:selected').text() === linea){
                repetido = 1;
            }
        })
;
```

// tambien intente esto

```
        $("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
            console.log($(this).text());
            if($(this).val().text() === linea){
                repetido = 1;
            }
        });
```

// mi solucion fue comparar el id
    $("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).val() === idLinea){
        repetido = 1;
    }
});

Comment: Deberías formular mejor tu pregunta ya que no se entiende que problema tienes.

Comment: ya esta corregido

Comment: la variable linea que representa?

Comment: ¿Dónde leíste que "*deberías*" obtenerlo con `.text()`? Estás equivocado... Se obtiene con `.val()`, tal cual estás diciendo en tu pregunta. Y sin jQuery, `tuInput.value`.

Comment: var linea = $('#idLinea option:selected').text() haci puedes obtener el conenido del campo si no lo sabias

Comment: Es algo confusa tu pregunta ya que como menciona @Mariano con el `.va()` deberias poder hacer la comparación sin problemas

Comment: la variable numero es un numero de 10 digitos  de un select que traigo de la base de datos

Comment: no quiero comparar el valor si no el contenido del input no es confuso

Comment: es que el valor de un `input` es su contenido es por eso te que digo q es confuso, si en un `input` escribes **'Hola Mundo'** cuando cuando ejecutes el `.val()`, te traerá el **'Hola Mundo'** si no es eso, dime que seria contenido? para poderte entender.

Comment: tienes razon es un select  value="1"  <option>1234567890</option>

Comment: Ok ahora si, cuando aclaras que es un select se entiende mejor, entonces la variable linea, almacenaría el contenido del select no su value.

Comment: @Carlos para evitar seguir adivinando qué valor estás intentando obtener, por favor agrega el HTML de tu input en la pregunta

Answer (score 9):

Deberías utilizar el método `text` sobre el `option` seleccionado, no sobre el elemento `select`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#obtener').click(function(){
    console.log('El texto seleccionado es:',
      $('select[name="lineas"] option:selected').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="lineas">
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opción 4</option>
  <option value="5">Opción 5</option>
</select>

<button id="obtener">Obtener texto</button>
```

Comment: no me funciona no me imprime el console    $("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log($('select[name="lineas"] option:selected').text());
    if($('select[name="lineas"] option:selected').text() === linea){
     repetido = 1;
    }
   });

Comment: Pero ¿por qué lo recorres con un `each`? ¿Tienes varios elementos con nombre `lineas`? ¿O tratas de recorrer todas las opciones del `select`? Estaría bien que incluyeras el código HTML en la pregunta para que nos hagamos una idea más concreta de lo que intentas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comentan @Mariano es correcto, `.val()` y `.text()` son cosas distintas y, si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de tu input, tendrías que hacerlo similar a:

```
var linea = 'Texto de prueba'
$("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log(linea);
    if($(obj).val() == linea) {
        repetido = 1;
    }
});
```

Como puedes observar, solo cambié agregué una linea definiendo tu variable a comparar, también cambié la palabra `$(this)` a `$(obj)` aunque esto no tendría que tener ningún efecto en el funcionamiento.

Answer (score 0):

ya quedo aqui lo dejo queria comparar el contenido del select no el valor

ejemplo

```
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opción 4</option>
  <option value="5">Opción 5</option>

   var opcion = "Opción 5";

            $("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
                if($(this).text() === opcion ){
                    repetido = 1;
                }
            });

  //haci queria mas o menos que quedara pero bueno tuve que comparar los id

 opcion2 = 1;
$("input[name='lineas']").each(function(i, obj) {
    if($(this).val() === opcion2 ){
        repetido = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Deberías editar la propia pregunta para añadir la información adicional. Por lo que entiendo lo que tratas de hacer es comprobar si existe una opción determinada dentro del select ¿es así?

Comment: no , solo era una comparacion del texto que esta escrito en un select en el option y validar que no fueran iguales.  texto1 == texto1 por ejemplo